# Importing decorated functions

Tags: python, import

I have a number of functions in separate files with pynodered decorators, which pynodered will import one by one.

so I call from the command line.

```
pynodered file1.py file2.py
```

these file1.py etc. look like this

```
from pynodered import node_red

@node_red(name="Unblock user",
              title="Unblock User in AD",
    def unblock_user(node, msg):
```

However I would like to have one big file to import them all (basically because it is easier to manage which nodes to load)

```
import file1
import file2
```

and then start pynodered like

```
pynodered bigfile.py
```

But apparently this doesn't work as it cannot register the functions
Exception: Zero function or class to register to Node-RED has been found. Check your python files

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

hmm. that is interesting. i was tryign to break up my one single bigfile to do opposite of you.
my current big file has the decorators for around 5 or 6 functions intwo different categories.
they all show up fine.

The following description from pynodered will be useful for you

```
"""
def node_red(name=None, title=None, category="default", description=None,
             join=None, baseclass=RNBaseNode, properties=None, icon=None, color=None, outputs=1, output_labels=None):
    decorator to make a python function available in node-red. The function must take two arguments, node and msg.
    msg is a dictionary with all the pairs of keys and value sent by node-red. Most interesting keys are 'payload', 
    'topic' and 'msgid_'.
    The node argument is an instance of the underlying class created by this decorator. It can be useful when you 
    have a defined a common subclass
    of RNBaseNode that provided specific features for your application (usually database connection and similar).
```

"""